# How to synchronize changes in nosql db (ravendb)

Tags: c#, nosql, ravendb

I've started learning NoSQL on an example of RavenDB. I've started with a simplest model, let's say we have topics that were created by users:

```
public class Topic
{
    public string Id { get; protected set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public string Text { get; set; }

    public DenormalizedUser User { get; set; }
}

public class DenormalizedUser
{
    public string Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}

public class User
{
    public string Id { get; protected set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public DateTime Birthdate { get; set; }

    //some other fields
}
```

We don't need the whole `User` for displaying a `Topic`, so I've denormalized it to `DenormalizedUser`, containing an `Id` and a `Name`.

So, here are the questions:

1) Is this approach correct for NoSQL?

2) How to handle cases when `User` changes the `Name`? Do I need to manually update all the `Name` fields in denormalized classes?

Comment: Not sure for question 1. As for 2, yes you would have to update the field for 'Name' in 'DenormalizedUser' too because strings, for all intents and purposes, are handled by value, not reference. I don't just see why you can't only use 'User' - 'DenormalizedUser' reeks of pointless and redundant data. _Edited (multiple times) for clarity and grammar. I need more coffee._

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Shaddix you can use the Raven DB Include function to load the User using the UserId from your topic.

```
var topic = _session.Load<Topic>(topicId)
                    .Customize(x => x.Include<Topic>(y => y.UserId));

var user = _session.Load<User>(topic.UserId);
```

The Load for Topic will 'preload' the User and both Loads will only result in one GET request. (I couldn't reply directly  to your response to Ayende due to my reputation).

You also use the alternative (and probably clearer) .Include() function without Customize().

http://docs.ravendb.net/consumer/querying/handling-document-relationships.html

Comment: Thanks, that's the way to go, but if I'm querying for the list of Topics and I have not only a `User` as a reference inside the `Topic`, the syntax become overcomplicated compared to NH (example on dlang's comment)..

Comment: There's an example of querying in the document relationships link above.

`var topics = session.Query<Topic>().Customize(x => x.Include<Topic>(t => t.UserId)).ToList();`
 
You can then add each to your view model:

`foreach (var topic in topics)
{
    var user = session.Load<User>(topic.UserId);
    // viewmodel list.Add(new TopicViewModel { .... });
}`

It isn't as 'clean' as NH for example, but I think the time gained and headaches lost using Raven outweigh that. You could also bundle it in to some extension method to clean up your controllers/services if need be.

Comment: it's a good point to think about extension method, yes. Thanks for the link provided, it really describes all the possible ways here. It's a pity with all the good and "native" c# api not to have this.. I'll go take a look at MongoDB's world, but I think their API would be worse at other points.

Answer (score 3):

shaddix,
You don't need to denormalize, you can hold a reference to the id and then Include that when you load from the server

Comment: Thanks, Ayende, but if I only have UserId, how could I access `topic.User.Name`? Sure, I can do `_session.Query<User>().Where(x=>x.Id==topic.UserId)`, but it'd be much less convenient than in RDBMS with NHibernate where I could have reference to the `User` inside the `Topic`, or are there other ways?

Answer (score 2):

1) Yes, this approach works fine and the result is, that you only need to load the topic-document when you want to display it along with the name of its user. However, as Ayende states, the perfomance will be nearly the same as if you didn't denormalize the user and just include it when needed. If you don't worry about multiple-server deployment I recommend that approach.

2) If you really want to denormalize the user, then you can update all topics referencing this user simply with a set based operation. Look at this: http://ravendb.net/faq/denormalized-updates

Comment: I'm ok with doing `.Include` especially because it's still only one DB-hit, I'm only worried about ease of use in that case. Let's say I'd like to get a ViewModel with a list of topics and their users, how would I do that with Include? `_session.Query<Topic>().Include(x => x.UserId).Select(topic => new {Topic = topic, User = _session.Query<User>().Where(u => u.Id == topic.UserId )})`? In NHibernate it'd be only: `_session.Query<Topic>().Fetch(x => x.User)` with reference to `User` inside the `Topic`, and it looks much cleaner, hope to find similar with nosql...

Comment: Your code-example of how to use `.Include` is really nice and yes, it works that way. I'm using NHibernate since many years and I agree, using `.Fetch` and referencing the User directly is much cleaner. If someone is using RavenDB correctly you will see it in his data-model.