# Designing link objects

Tags: c#, nosql, ravendb

When I design documents I usually use link documents to define relations between different document types.

Something like:

**EmailDocument**

- Id
- Subject
- UserLink

  - DisplayName
  - UserId

**User**

- Id
- FirstName
- LastName

The problem is if a user changes it's name, the old name are left in all related documents. Is the link documents a bad approach or are there an easy way to update all those links? (I usually create a class called `User` and one called `UserLink`. `UserLink` is included in all other documents that has a relation to a user.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, I don't think it's a bad approach, since it will improve performance in many cases. But it does add complexity and require you to have a strategy for updating the name when the parent entity changes (User).

A common design around this is to expose events - when the event "UserChangedName" is raised, you can have a listener that updates all DisplayName's in all EmailDocument instances.

Answer (score 1):

Related post here - [How to synchronize changes in nosql db (ravendb)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7753296/how-to-synchronize-changes-in-nosql-db-ravendb)

I'd just store a UserId field inside the EmailDocument that provides a reference to the specific User. Raven provides an include function to pull in related documents within your current session/query, with no (or at least very little - Raven is read optimized after all) additional cost and no extra GET request.

http://docs.ravendb.net/consumer/querying/handling-document-relationships.html

```
var email = session.Include<EmailDocument>(x => x.UserId)
                   .Load(id);

 var user = session.Load<User>(email.UserId);
```

This will result in one GET request that pulls in both documents, and you'll also have all the additional information the User document provides, you can build your view models from both objects. You'll also do away with the overhead of having to keep track of name changes and updating each document when those changes do occur.